# How to add items to array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I iterate through an existing array and add the items to a new array.

```
var array = [];
forEach( calendars, function (item, index) {
    array[] = item.id
}, done );

function done(){
   console.log(array);
}
```

The above code would normally work in JS, not sure about the alternative in `node js`. I tried `.push` and `.splice` but neither worked.

Comment: There are a lot of wrong things with your code; that implies you haven't tried very hard to get it working!  For instance, what is happening with `array[] = item.id`?  That would produce a syntax error in normal js.

Answer (score 170):

Check out [Javascript's Array API](http://www.javascripture.com/Array) for details on the exact syntax for Array methods. Modifying your code to use the correct syntax would be:

```
var array = [];
calendars.forEach(function(item) {
    array.push(item.id);
});

console.log(array);
```

You can also use the `map()` method to generate an Array filled with the results of calling the specified function on each element.  Something like:

```
var array = calendars.map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
});

console.log(array);
```

And, since ECMAScript 2015 has been released, you may start seeing examples using `let` or `const` instead of `var` and the `=>` syntax for creating functions.  The following is equivalent to the previous example (except it may not be supported in older node versions):

```
let array = calendars.map(item => item.id);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is example which can give you some hints to iterate through existing array and add items to new array. I use UnderscoreJS Module to use as my utility file.

You can download from (https://npmjs.org/package/underscore)

```
$ npm install underscore
```

Here is small snippet to demonstrate how you can do it.

```
var _ = require("underscore");
var calendars = [1, "String", {}, 1.1, true],
    newArray = [];

_.each(calendars, function (item, index) {
    newArray.push(item);
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var array = [];

//length array now = 0
array[array.length] = 'hello';
//length array now = 1
//            0
//array = ['hello'];//length = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = calendars.map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
});

console.log(array);
```