# Construct array in nodejs through for loop

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

I am using sails (0.11.0) running on nodejs (6.9.1). I am trying to construct an array by filling it through for loop. I would send this completed array in response to the client. I have tried various methods as suggested by people here on Stack Overflow, for example

the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491101/javascript-create-array-from-for-loop) suggested

```
for (var i = yearStart; i < yearEnd+1; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}
```

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084570/how-to-add-items-to-array-in-nodejs) discussion, it is suggested to use:

```
var array = calendars.map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
});

console.log(array);
```

Similarly I tried many methods but I am coming across the same issue that during the loop, the array gets filled but as soon as the loop is completed, the array gets empty because of asynchronous process and therefore I can not send the response. To tackle with this I tried checking the index inside the loop body and send response from inside the loop body itself through

```
var userArray = [];
_.each(users, function(user, index){
  MySQLConnector.query('CALL user_image (?)', [user.id], function(err, userImage){
    if(err){
      return res.json({"status":"some_error"});
    }else{
      userID = user.id
      userImageID = userImage[0][0].id;
      var userInfo = {
        userID: userID,
        userImageID: userImageID
      }
      userArray.push(userInfo)
      if(index == users.length - 1){
          res.json({selectedUsers: userArray});
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I am initiating an empty **userArray** and then iterate through **users** object where each element of the object is characterized by name **user** and an **index**. Through a MySQL query I am fetching the **userImage** object and in each iteration, I am creating an object called **userInfo** that consists of **userID** and **userImageID**. I am pushing this object into **userArray**. And after each iteratio of the for loop (`_.each`), I check if last index is reached. Once last index is reached, the final array is sent as response before loop body is complete.

Here too I have an issue that the array body is not always completely filled. The reason is due to asynchronous process, the **index** does not always follow the order 0,1,2,3,4,.... and it can start with any number and can jump to any index in the next iteration, for example the first index to start would be 4, the second would be 0, third would be 2 and so on. This sequence would be different for every time we run this for loop. For a user, it will appear to be a total random process. Therefore if **users.length** is 8, and current index is randomly 7 at third iteration, the condition `index == users.length - 1` will be met and response will be sent just with an array consisting of 3 elements rather than 8.

Can someone suggest me a better and robust way to fill an array through the for loop in nodejs and send that array in response, so that all items are included in the array in their original order?

Comment: It will not follow the order and i think you're going to have the same issue with map too. Have a look at reduce in lodash and bluebird, i know in the latter it will guarantee the order, i think it lodash it would be the same but might be wrong about that.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, in the async library, i often use eachSeries, this guarantees the order too and would likely be a solution for your existing code.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using node js , it is better to use any promises library like [**bluebird**](https://caolan.github.io/async/) or [**async**](https://caolan.github.io/async/) to handle Async requests. 
The reason your loop is not working as expected is because as you've pointed out, due to async requests taking time to resolve for which `_.each` loop is not waiting.

Using `bluebird`, it can be done with [**Promise.map**](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) method which works as explained below from the documentaion :

> Given an Iterable(arrays are Iterable), or a promise of an Iterable,
>   which produces promises (or a mix of promises and values), iterate
>   over all the values in the Iterable into an array and map the array to
>   another using the given mapper function.
>
> Promises returned by the mapper function are awaited for and the
>   returned promise doesn't fulfill until all mapped promises have
>   fulfilled as well. If any promise in the array is rejected, or any
>   promise returned by the mapper function is rejected, the returned
>   promise is rejected as well.

Hence, Using `Promise.map` your code can be updated like below :

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");     

return Promise.map(users, function(user, index){
  return MySQLConnector.query('CALL user_image (?)', [user.id], function(err, userImage){
    if(err){
      return Promise.reject({"status":"some_error"});
    }else{
      userID = user.id
      userImageID = userImage[0][0].id;
      var userInfo = {
        userID: userID,
        userImageID: userImageID
      }
      return userInfo;
    }
  });
})
.then(function (usersArray){
  res.json({selectedUsers: usersArray});
})
.catch(function (err){
  res.json(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, going to try the promise library.

Comment: Still I am getting the response array as `[null,null,null,null,null,null]`

Comment: It should work, maybe the response you are getting is null. Can you put a log before returning `userInfo` in the success callback and check once.

Comment: Yes, this null array is coming from log itself.

Comment: Did you check the value of `userImage` after the query ?

Comment: Yes. I have put logs everywhere. The userImage is getting retrieved.

Comment: Maybe it's not returned from inside the query. Can you put a `return` in front of your `MySQLConnector.query` statement and check

Comment: Did that too, still same output. Anyways solved the problem using the comparison method as I stated in the problem statement, instead of using index, I used iteration count to match with `users.length` and also attached **index** along with **id** and **imageID** to the **userInfo** object. After construction of full array, sorted it on **index** key and sent as response.

Comment: +1 for the Bluebird solution as v1 of Sails provides opt in support for bluebirds promises for the actions like create(), update(), etc. Side note, take a look at reduce in Bluebird too.

Comment: @harshvardhan: Good to know that you've solved the problem. But , the Bluebird way is the correct way to handle this kind of issues. I'm not sure why it didn't work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute loops with functions with callbacks synchronously using [SynJS](https://github.com/amaksr/SynJS):

```
var SynJS = require('synjs');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'tracker',
  password : 'tracker123',
  database : 'tracker'
});


function myFunction1(modules,connection,users) {
    var ret=[];
    for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
        connection.query("SELECT CONCAT('some image of user #',?) AS userImage", [users[i]], function(err, rows, fields) {
              if (err) throw err;

              ret.push({
                  id: users[i],
                  image:    rows[0].userImage
              });
              modules.SynJS.resume(_synjsContext); // <-- indicate that callback is finished
        });
        SynJS.wait(); // <-- wait for callback to finish
    }
    return ret;
};

var modules = {
        SynJS:  SynJS,
        mysql:  mysql,
};

var users = [1,5,7,9,20,21];

SynJS.run(myFunction1,null,modules,connection,users,function (ret) {
    console.log('done. result is:');
    console.log(ret);
});
```

Result would be following:

```
done. result is:
[ { id: 1, image: 'some image of user #1' },
  { id: 5, image: 'some image of user #5' },
  { id: 7, image: 'some image of user #7' },
  { id: 9, image: 'some image of user #9' },
  { id: 20, image: 'some image of user #20' },
  { id: 21, image: 'some image of user #21' } ]
```